# shirk in islam accountability

Tags: shirk

hi does anyone have any advice , every time i do something for Allah SWT for example , dua , surah recitation , dhikr or any act of worship for Allah. these people keep popping up in my head and it feels like i’m directing my worship towards them and not Allah. these people are so random and have no role in my life whatsoever but i know they’re not God they’re just Allah’s creation. it feels like im committing shirk but i don’t know. and i was just testing myself and i told myself you have to make an intention towards the person and i accidentally made intention towards that person and went “ ya “ while thinking of him. does this count as shirk but i was just testing myself. will Allah forgive me ? does this count as shirk ? or PLEASE I NEED HELP.

Comment: It's easy to get rid of these "people". Ask me anything you want. I'm here to help people.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get rid of these "people" from your mind.

This is called complusions.

First, you have to know that those are nothing except your **PURE IMAGINATION**. They don't exist. I'm pretty sure they are here because once Shaytan told you "they" exist and you were scared so you started thinking of the idea but thinking of the idea only made it stick to your head and made it worse.

Secondly, what did Allah say about this ? Allah said **"Fa a'lam anahu La Ilaha ila Allah" ("Know, therefore, that there is no God but Allah")**. Allah is too Wise to lie to you about this. And know that it can only be written in the Quran if only one God exists, otherwise "the other god won't let it be written".

Lastly, just know that the fact that this thing can even come up in your mind is absolutely stupid, you don't realize it now but you'll realize it later. **So you shouldn't even bother yourself thinking about this, because it's just dumb. Why would you think of something that makes you depressed instead of forgetting about it, if you KNOW it's false??**

And just know it's false, there's no way the Lord of the Worlds lied to you, it's just dumb and stupid. It's false, no doubt about it. And if you just read this and your mind told you "umm, but what if it's not?" then know that Shaytan is right next to you extremely happy about your situation.

Don't listen to Shaytan (devil), he is here to lie to you.

You will probably cry but, whether you did shirk or not, you should stop this from coming into your brain. If you did shirk, then ask for forgiveness, shirk is huge. If you didn't, then you're infinitely close to it, so you better forget about it.

**TRUST ME, IT'S WRONG!! You'll realize how dumb it is when you it stops coming to your mind**. *you can ask for more help*

Edit : and they're not even Allah's creation, they're your creation.